# Always resolve inter-party rock-paper-scissors the way I want to?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I want Scarlett and Roderick to have particular traits, which means they will occasionally have to disagree on the proper course of action; however, I usually want one course of action to win over the other.

Currently, I'm quicksaving and quickloading in order to save scum the result I want; however, this is pretty time consuming.

Is there some way to guarantee a particular outcome? Note that I'm playing in single-player, so I can't seem to control what the other character does during rock-paper-scissors and auto-resolving is random.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems your second character, in your case Roderick, picks always the same until the left character wins one time. Then the right character shifts one to the left.

When the left character starts with paper and the right one with the scissors, the right one will choose the scissors as long as you choose paper. This way the right char wins the argument.
If you switch to stone and thus beat the scissors, the right char will move one symbol to the left. So his choice will be paper the next time. You can now choose the scissors and beat him again. Also he will again move one symbol to the left and choose stone.
So you can "go in circles" and win the argument with the left character.

Comment: Sounds like real life arguments, just go in circles until the other person gives up!

Comment: I noticed something yesterday. This behaviour seems only to work with your two characters. Other NPCs seem to react in a different way.

Comment: @Tom That is correct, but other NPCs also follow a system. AFAIK it's never truly random, you'll need to figure out how the NPC's choosing his/her option